# Why to specify the size of Array in Java if it is an Object and stored on heap?

Tags: java, arrays

I am coming from a C++ background and I have just started learning java. I am not able to understand why do I need to provide the size of an array before compiling even though it is an object and is stored on heap?

Any examples that could help me clear up the concept are welcome.

Comment: You don't always have to specify the size. You can always use an initializer list: `int[] nums = new int[] {1, 2, 3};`

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking exactly. When you create an array on the heap in C++, you also need to specify its size; there is no difference between C++ and Java in that respect. Perhaps a little code makes it clearer what you are asking for.

Comment: @LoganKulinski That specifies an array of size 3

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt it does, but his question is unclear to begin with. Is he referencing the fact that arrays are not dynamic?

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt In C++ a C-Style array is stored on the stack but if I use a vector which is stored on a heap, I can dynamically expand its size based on my requirement but the java array is stored on a heap so why do I need to provide its size beforehand i.e why can't I expand it on basis of my requirement?

Comment: @Manav you might be looking for `ArrayList`.

Comment: For examples, see http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/99/arrays/404/creating-and-initializing-arrays#t=201701290545103127755

Comment: Short answer:  `int[] array = new int[someExpression];`  The size of the array is not fixed at compile time.  (This is equivalent to how you allocate an array in the heap in C or C++)

Comment: @Manav In C++ you have to choice of storing the array on the stack or on the heap (in both cases you need to specify the size on allocation). You aren't talking about an array but about a higher-level datastructure (vector) that uses (and reallocates) arrays underneath. Java also has these - `ArrayList` is the one that comes closest.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Thanks for your input. I think I got my answer. I'll look into ArrayList now!

Answer (score 0):

If you create an array

```
int[] ia = new int[0];
```

It's size cannot be changed later, so if you try to add a value, you get an out of bounds exception. If this does not work for your program, you should use an ArrayList which is an object that does not have a defined size so while terrible this code should work:

```
ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(int q = 0; q < 10000; q++){ //Infinitely add ints to the ArrayList
   int i = 1;
   al.add((Integer) i);
}
```

Comment: Solved, didn't test first @VGR

Answer (score 0):

> I am not able to understand why do I need to provide the size of an array before compiling…

You don't need to provide the size before compiling. For example, the following code allows the user to provide the size at runtime:

```java
final Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Array size: ");
final int[] array = new int[input.nextInt()];
System.out.printf("The array size is %d.\n", array.length);
```

If you'd like an easy-to-resize array-like object, [`ArrayList`s](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) are very nice.